# Get list at site collection level using SP.js

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have this code which is meant to get data from a list at the site collection level.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_site().openWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    var query = "query here";

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

I had modified the lines below which gets data from the current web

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();


    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
```

to this

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_site().openWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
```

Usually you open the site then the web and then get to the list but it doesn't seem to work in JS.

Can you please point out what I need to do fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft API is so complicated.... You may want to try [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) or the library I created: [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/)

With SharepointPlus you'll do something like:

```
$SP().list("ListName", "URL of the site collection").get({fields:"Title",where:"ID = 1"}, function(data) {
  // do something with 'data'
})
```

That way the script will query the webservices and retrieves the data from the site collection level based on the URL provided.

Note: you need to know the URL of the site collection -- if you don't know it, then search on Google because there are several ways to find it with JavaScript.